# Is there any way to refresh the compose window through a Gmail Addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I've created an addon that, upon user request, replaces the attachments with a password-protected zip. It basically reads the draft and updates it with the new attachment, thus removing the previous ones, using something like this:

```
draft.update(message.getTo(),message.getSubject(), message.getBody(), {attachments: zipAttachment, cc:message.getCc(), bcc:message.getBcc(),  htmlBody: message.getBody()});
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that the draft email is correct but the changes are not reflected on the compose window. If the user closes the compose window and re-opens it from the draft, it's fine, but I would like to "refresh" the compose window with the updated version of the message.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you solve this issue. I'm also looking for a solution for this.

Comment: No unfortunately not

Comment: any solution for this